# How to go back with Cordova Android?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am making an Android app with Phonegap Cordova and I have a problem with the back button
I would like to go back to the previouspage in my app
I was looking for some examples but I'm stuck now

I tried this :

```
document.addEventListener('backbutton', backPressed, false);

    function backPressed()
    {
        navigator.app.backHistory();
    }
```

It can enter the backPressed() function but navigator.app.backHistory() doesn't work

I also tried with history.back(-1) but it doesn't work too

**I don't know if I need to install a cordova plugin**

Thank your for your help

Answer (score 0):

**Finally,**

`navigator.app.backHistory()` is working fine but my problem was elsewhere. 
I was using `window.location.replace` to change pages which was not capturing the page navigation history.